# use awk to process a csv (tab delimited) line by line

Tags: shell, csv, awk, line

sorry if this is impossible to do with AWK, but this is something I can think of with AWK.

I have a CSV file (tab delimited) that has about 10 columns with a big header section. The content is like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10
```

I don't need to filter by col1-9, but only need to look at col10 line by line. The content in each row of col10 is like this

```
int1/int2: int3,int4: int5: int6
```

My filtering condition is: `if int3 + int4 >= 30`, I'll print it out to a new csv file, otherwise filter it out (no print).

Is this possible to do with AWK in combination with shell scripts (read line by line?)? thanks a lot for reading my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{ t = $10
split(t,x,":")
split(x[2],a,",")
}(a[1]+a[2])>=30' oldcsv > newcsv
```

or shorter:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{t=$10; split(t,a,/[:,]/)}(a[3]+a[2])>=30' oldcsv > newcsv
```

didn't test, but should work, if the format of $10 is fixed.

Comment: Nice job there .. wanted to know what is the return type for split and wheter you need to print it specifically @kent ?

Comment: @woofmeow my gawk man page tells :`return the number of fields.` No, I don't need. a true value by default is print

Comment: @Kent: thank you so much for your answer. Since my CSV files have some header lines (20 lines) that I want to keep in the new CSV. Can you guide me how to retain these header lines in your command? Thanks again